# Class that converts converts to an index and pointer and referes to a container

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion

I try to write a class that accesses an element in a container by its index. I therefore will be able to re-route the container pointed to (but that is not really important for my current problem). It will help me to get rid of complicated copy constructors.

This class should behave as if it's a number (i.e. the index) and as if it's a pointer (i.e. to which it points). I therefore have conversion. I however get compiler errors:

```
In instantiation of 'class paxRef<Dog&, std::vector<Dog> >': 
34:47: required from here 
13:5: error: forming pointer to reference type 'Dog&'
In function 'int main()': 
37:7: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'paxRef<Dog&, std::vector<Dog> >' 
38:7: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'paxRef<Dog&, std::vector<Dog> >' 
44:43: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'paxRef<Dog&, std::vector<Dog> >' 
45:43: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'paxRef<Dog&, std::vector<Dog> >'
```

What does `forming pointer to reference type 'Dog&'` mean? Do I really need to define a `->`operator if I have an implicit conversion to a pointer? Is it possible to shorten the `paxRef<decltype(v.back()), decltype(v)>` syntax and is it causing the above errors?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <class T, class C>
class paxRef
{
public:
    paxRef(size_t index, C* container) : _index(index), _container(container) { } 
    //implicit conversion
    operator size_t() const { return _index; }
    operator T*() { return &(_container->at(_index)); }
    //operator ->() { return T*(); } // Do I need to define the -> operator if I already have a pointer-conversion operator?
private:
    size_t _index;
    C* _container;
};


class Dog
{
public:
    std::string bark() { return _sound; }
    void setName(std::string sound) { _sound=sound; }
private:
    std::string _sound = "Wuff";
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Dog> v(5);
    paxRef<decltype(v.back()), decltype(v)> r2(2, &v); // Very verbos.
    paxRef<decltype(v.back()), decltype(v)> r4(4, &v); // Can I drop the < ... > part somehow?

    r2->setName("Bello");
    r4->setName("Fatty");

    for(size_t i{ 0 }; i<v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout<<"Dog at "<<i<<" says "<<v.at(i).bark()<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"ref at "<<r2<<" says "<<r2->bark()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"ref at "<<r4<<" says "<<r4->bark()<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: i suspect your usage of `decltype(v.back())` for your instantiations isn't what you want there. I'd be more inclined to use `decltype(v)::value_type` instead. You could also use `std::remove_reference<decltype(v.back())>::type`, but honestly I wouldn't see the point unless your shooting for cryptic. I also would be inclined to use a reference rather than a pointer for your container member.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to explicitly define `operator->` even though you have an implicit conversion to a pointer.

The standard states in 
[over.match.oper]/2

> If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, a user-defined operator function might be
>   declared that implements this operator or a user-defined conversion can be necessary to convert the operand
>   to a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator. In this case, overload resolution is used to determine
>   which operator function or built-in operator is to be invoked to implement the operator. [...]

Overload resolution is then described in [over.match.oper]/3, the relevant part for this case being [over.match.oper]/3.3:

> For the `operator,`, the unary `operator &`, or the `operator ->`, the built-in candidates set is empty. [...]

This means that no conversions that would allow a call to the build-in `operator->` (in this case for `Dog*`) are considered, and there has to be a member or non-member definition of `operator->` for your class.

Regarding the explicit annotation of the template arguments: 
You can get around that by defining a templated helper function `make_paxref` similar to `make_tuple` or `make_pair` that does the type deduction. Or you can wait for C++17 where template argument deduction will also work for constructors of templated classes :)